# Can 49 Linearly independent vectors of $R^{50}$ Generate a 49th dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can the spam of 49 linearly independent vectors of $R^{50}$ generate the 49th Dimension? This question comes from the following idea. Please feel free to correct me.

The span of One vector of $R^2$ can generate a line that goes on from the origin.

The span of two linearly independent vectors can generate at most a plane.

Given this pattern, what can three linearly independent vectors of $R^4$ generate the 3rd Dimension and so on.

Will this pattern extend to n-1 dimensions? Thus, can 49 linearly independent vectors of $R^{50} generate the 49th dimension.

Edit: Thank you, I got the concept.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate the 49th dimension?"  If you have $k$ linearly independent vectors of an $n$-dimensional space., their span will be a $k$-dimensional subspace...

Comment: But in this case I have 49 vectors with 50th components, rather than 49 linearly independent vectors with 49th components that would generate the 49th dimension. I am just trying to make a relationship from how with 2 vectors that have 3 components i can make a plane that would be $R^2$.

Comment: If you have $k$ linearly independent vectors with $n$ components, they will generate a $k$-dimensional space.  There is no relationship needed between $k$ and $n$.  It is not unique to using $n-1$ vectors in an $n$ dimensional space

Comment: Got it thank you.

Comment: Two independent vectors with three components do span a plane, but it is _not_ $\mathbb R^2$. Those vectors aren’t even elements of $\mathbb R^2$ to begin with. The plane they span is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ that is _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb R^2$, but that’s not the same thing as its _being_ $\mathbb R^2$ at all.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. That difference was pointed out to me earlier and was the answer I was looking for to this problem. I cannot say that 49 linearly independent vectors of $R^{50}$ make up a 49th dimensional space I can however, say that they make a subspace of $R^{50}$

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "generate the 49th dimension", but here's what we can say: For any positive integer $n$, if you take $n-1$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, then these vectors generate an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

So, if you choose $n=50$, and you take $49$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{50}$, then their span will be a $49$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{50}$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I would be generating the 49th dimensional subspace of $R^{50}$ not the 49th dimension.

Comment: @Josue by the way, when your use of the word "the" is incorrect. saying "the 49th dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{50}$" suggests that there is a unique $49$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{50}$. But this is not the case; there are infinitely many subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^{50}$ which have dimension $49$ (just like there are infinitely many one-dimensional lines in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$). (if that was merely a mix-up in language then it's fine, but otherwise, I hope you understand the distinction)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Josue's mother tongue might be a language (such as Russian) where they don't distinguish between "a" and "the". Weird but true. Funny nick BTW.

Comment: haha, thanks for the grammar lesson.